# How to get BIOS source?

Tags: bios

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.win-raid.com/t871f50-Guide-How-to-get-full-NVMe-support-for-all-Systems-with-an-AMI-UEFI-BIOS.html) guide in order to setup a new NVME drive as my boot drive on a Z77 system, but the first step of the guide requires me to have a "'pure' (completely extracted) source BIOS file'

What is a 'pure' source BIOS file? Can it be extracted from the .ffs file I used to flash my BIOS? If not, how do I get one?

Comment: The link you gave says "An up-to-date BIOS for the related mainboard (original or already pre-modified)".

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. I updated my bios by flashing it with a .ffs I got from my Mobo downloads site (AsRock Extreme4 Z77). I also have to the option to get windows or dos executables, but I doubt that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

By “completely extracted” the guide means just that: You have the actual firmware image present. Mainboard manufacturers often pack these files multiple times.

For example, they could offer a “firmware update boot disk creator” in a ZIP archive. This creator itself has the firmware image packed somewhere inside it. And that’s what you’d need to extract.

For your motherboard, the manufacturer offers the image itself, it’s called “Instant Flash”. This’ll get you a file called `Z77EXT42.90` (or similar, depends on the version). This file should be usable with the rest of the guide.

If it isn’t, you’re out of luck. This guide is only for a specific UEFI implementation.

/edit: Oh yeah, there’s also a beta firmware available that supposedly supports NVMe.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it again with your information in mind. I already tried the beta firmware provided on their website. That only let the BIOS recognize the device and even makes it selectable in the boot options, but it doesn't know how to boot from it. I tried making a Windows installation USB, but it tells me that the necessary controller is missing for that device to be bootable, despite using the nvme beta firmware.